# How to use the JDA interface in another class

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, static, discord-jda

I played JDA in the Spring-boot framework.
However, there is a situation where you have to send a DM to a user at a specific URL.
I play JDABuilder in a class called Main. But in my controller, there is no way to call up the JDA I declared in Main (except static), is there any other way?

WebApplication

```
public class WebApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, InvalidHandlerException {
        SpringApplication.run(PortfolioWebApplication.class, args); 
        Main main = new Main();
        main.main();
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(PortfolioWebApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```java
public void main() throws LoginException, InvalidHandlerException {
    token token = new token();
    JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token.tokenStr).build();
    System.out.println("======START======");
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AjaxmemberUpdat2.do", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
private @ResponseBody String memberUpdate2(@RequestBody PartyVO partyVO) {
    String flage;
    try {
        partyMapper.partymemberUpdate2(partyVO);
        String userId = partyVO.getDiscordid();
        if(!userId.equals(null)) {
            jda.openPrivateChannelById(userId)
                    .flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage(""))
                    .queue();
        }
        flage = "true";
        return flage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        flage = "false";
        return flage;
    }
}
```

At first, I tried to solve JDABuilder using static variable.
But I'm looking for another way after hearing that static is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need some kind of access.
You definitely have to store your JDA instance - there is no other way.
Whether you store it as a static variable or not is up to you.
I don‘t see why static should be dangerous as long as your backend is save.

As soon as you start to use several shards, you can change the single JDA instance to eg. a Map.

What I would do and am using (except I am using a Map) is:

```
public abstract class Main {

   private static JDA jda;

   public void main() throws LoginException, InvalidHandlerException {
      token token = new token();
      jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token.tokenStr).build();
      System.out.println("======START======");
   }

}
```

I also know a developer with 1,000,000 servers who uses it this way…

*Also: You should use camel-case starting with an uppercase letter for your class names as suggested by conventions.*